# Trouble with Buttons for subsetting data in Plotly [ R ]

Tags: r, r-plotly, magrittr

I am attempting to add a button for my plotly graph, below is some reprex data:

```
reprex <- tibble::tribble(            ~COURSE_DEPARTMENT,                    ~MAJOR_DESC,             ~STUDENT_CAMPUS_DESC, ~credit_hours,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",                   "Accounting",                           "CAPA",          1422,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",                   "Accounting",           "Inland Empire Campus",            24,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",                   "Accounting",             "Kern County Campus",           192,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",                   "Accounting",                    "Main Campus",          8402,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",                   "Accounting",           "Orange County Campus",            96,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",                   "Accounting",     "San Fernando Valley Campus",           620,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",                 "Anthropology",                           "CAPA",             4,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",                 "Anthropology",                    "Main Campus",            24,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",                  "Art History",                    "Main Campus",             4,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",            "Athletic Training",                    "Main Campus",             4,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",           "Behavioral Science",                           "CAPA",            28,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",           "Behavioral Science",                    "Main Campus",             4,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",                      "Biology",                           "CAPA",             8,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",                      "Biology",                    "Main Campus",           152,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",                 "Broadcasting",                           "CAPA",             8,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",                 "Broadcasting",                    "Main Campus",            72,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",      "Business Administration",          "*Central Coast Campus",            12,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",      "Business Administration",                           "CAPA",          2666,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",      "Business Administration", "High Desert Victorville Campus",           394,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",      "Business Administration",           "Inland Empire Campus",          1688,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",      "Business Administration",             "Kern County Campus",           352,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",      "Business Administration",                    "Main Campus",         32550,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",      "Business Administration",  "Naval Base-Ventura  (Pt Mugu)",          1463,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",      "Business Administration",           "Orange County Campus",          1175,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",      "Business Administration",     "San Fernando Valley Campus",          2381,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",      "Business Administration",                    "ULV On-Line",          3899,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",      "Business Administration",              "Vandenberg Center",           696,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",      "Business Administration",          "Ventura County Campus",           397,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",                    "Chemistry",                           "CAPA",             8,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",                    "Chemistry",                    "Main Campus",            32,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",            "Child Development",                           "CAPA",            36,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",            "Child Development",           "Inland Empire Campus",             8,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",            "Child Development",                    "Main Campus",            46,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",            "Child Development",           "Orange County Campus",            12,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics", "Child Development-Integrated",                    "Main Campus",             8,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",               "Communications",                           "CAPA",            20,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",               "Communications",                    "Main Campus",           128,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",  "Computer Sci & Computer Eng",                           "CAPA",            58,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",  "Computer Sci & Computer Eng",                    "Main Campus",           358,
                                    "Applied Sciences and Economics",             "Computer Science",                           "CAPA",             8
                                    )
```

so essentially I want to create a button that works off of the student campus column that gives me options to either aggregate everything into the whole campus, or separate by campus that the student is attending. Below is the code as I have it:

```
fig_test<- plot_ly(reprex,
                         x= ~COURSE_DEPARTMENT,
                         y = ~MAJOR_DESC,
                         text = ~credit_hours,
                         size = ~credit_hours,
                         type= 'scattergl',
                         mode = 'markers',
                         sizes = c(10,100),
                         color = ~MAJOR_DESC,
                         marker = list(opacity = 0.5, sizemode='diameter'))

fig_test <-fig_test %>% layout(title = 'Course Department vs Major by Billing Hours',
                                           xaxis = list(title='Course Department', showgrid=FALSE),
                                           yaxis = list(title = 'Student Major', showgrid = FALSE),
                                           showlegend = TRUE)
```

which give me this graph (from reprex data):

[image: fig_test]

what I'm hoping to do is to get a dropdown menu (or a button or even a slider would do) that will allow me to aggregate and disaggregate by the student's specific campus. I've tried adding buttons but it keeps giving me errors and I don't fully understand how to build them out properly.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is helpful to someone in the future, but I answered my own question using transforms within the plotly library:

```
fig_test<- plot_ly(reprex,
                         x= ~COURSE_DEPARTMENT,
                         y = ~MAJOR_DESC,
                         text = ~credit_hours,
                         size = ~credit_hours,
                         type= 'scattergl',
                         mode = 'markers',
                         sizes = c(10,100),
                         color = ~MAJOR_DESC,
                         marker = list(opacity = 0.5, sizemode='diameter'),
                   transforms = list(
                     list(
                       type = 'filter',
                       target = ~STUDENT_CAMPUS_DESC,
                       operation = '=',
                       value = unique(reprex$STUDENT_CAMPUS_DESC)[1]
                     )
                   ))

fig_test <-fig_test %>% 
  layout(title = 'Course Department vs Major by Billing Hours',
                                           xaxis = list(title='Course Department', showgrid=FALSE),
                                           yaxis = list(title = 'Student Major', showgrid = FALSE),
                                           showlegend = TRUE,
         updatemenus = list(
           list(
             type = 'dropdown',
             active = 0,
             buttons = list(
               list(method = "restyle",
                    args = list("transforms[0].value", unique(reprex$STUDENT_CAMPUS_DESC)[1]),
                    label = unique(reprex$STUDENT_CAMPUS_DESC)[1]),
               list(method = "restyle",
                    args = list("transforms[0].value", unique(reprex$STUDENT_CAMPUS_DESC)[2]),
                    label = unique(reprex$STUDENT_CAMPUS_DESC)[2]),
               list(method = "restyle",
                    args = list("transforms[0].value", unique(reprex$STUDENT_CAMPUS_DESC)[3]),
                    label = unique(reprex$STUDENT_CAMPUS_DESC)[3])
             )
           )
         )
  )
fig_test
```

So, essentially the transforms argument in the first half of the code allows you to call from a custom target vector, in this case the campus. The only issue I can readily see is that you would have to write a new line for each "button" you want to insert. Also, not sure if this could be solved with a four loop because this seems just a bit too brute force for me.